# Entity Framework - Reuse Complex Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an Entity in Code First Entity framework that currently looks like this:

```
public class Entity
{
    // snip ...

    public string OriginalDepartment { get; set; }
    public string OriginalQueue { get; set; }

    public string CurrentDepartment { get; set; }
    public string CurrentQueue { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create  Complex Type for these types as something like this:

```
public class Location
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Queue { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to use this same type for both Current and Original:

```
public Location Original { get; set; }
public Location Current { get; set; }
```

Is this possible, or do I need to create two complex types `CurrentLocation` and `OriginalLocation`?

```
public class OriginalLocation
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Queue { get; set; }
}

public class CurrentLocation
{
     public string Department { get; set; }
     public string Queue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is supported out of box, you do not need to create two complex types.

You can also configure your complex types explicitely with model builder

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<Location>();
```

To customize column names, you should configure them from parent entity configuration

```
public class Location
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Queue { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Location Original { get; set; }
    public Location Current { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<Location>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(x => x.Current.Queue).HasColumnName("myCustomColumnName");
    }
}
```

This will map `MyEntity.Current.Queue` to `myCustomName` column

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how it's supported out of the box. The `ComplexTypeConfiguration<T>` class has a `Property()` method that is asking me to specify a column name. The column name is going to be different for each one

Comment: I guess I should clarify that I want to be able to customize the column names for both complex types. Is that supported?

Comment: Do you want to have them only prefixed differently or have fully customized?

Comment: I'd prefer fully customized but I might be okay with just a prefix.

Comment: Ahh so I can put the column name on the entity configuration instead of the complex type one. Thanks!

Comment: @archil So are you saying that out of the box, _without_ customizing in the model builder, `public Location Original` would map out to `public string OriginalDepartment` and `public string OriginalQueue`?