# Entity Framework Nested database class

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework-5, castle-activerecord

Class definitions

```
Public Class AddressEntity
    Private _addressId As Guid
    Private m_strStreet As String
    Private m_strSuite As String
    Private m_strCity As String
    Private m_State As String
    Private m_strZipCode As String
    Private m_strCountry As String

    Public Overridable Property Street() As String
        Get
            Return m_strStreet
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            m_strStreet = Left(Value, 50)
            DataChanged(EntityState.Modified, "Street")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overridable Property Suite() As String
        Get
            Return m_strSuite
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            m_strSuite = Left(Value, 50)
            DataChanged(EntityState.Modified, "Suite")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overridable Property City() As String
        Get
            Return m_strCity
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            m_strCity = Left(Value, 50)
            DataChanged(EntityState.Modified, "City")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overridable Property State() As String
        Get
            Return m_State
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            m_State = Left(Value, 50)
            DataChanged(EntityState.Modified, "State")
        End Set
    End Property

    <MaxStringLength(10)>
    Public Overridable Property ZipCode() As String
        Get
            Return m_strZipCode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            m_strZipCode = Left(Value, 10)
            DataChanged(EntityState.Modified, "ZipCode")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overridable Property Country() As String
        Get
            Return m_strCountry
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            m_strCountry = Left(Value, 50)
            DataChanged(EntityState.Modified, "Country")
        End Set
    End Property

    <Key>
    Public Overridable Property AddressId() As Guid
        Get
            Return _addressId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Guid)
            _addressId = value
        End Set
    End Property


Public Class AMAStatementEntity
    Private _DateOfService As Nullable(Of DateTime)
    Private _FacilityLocation As AddressEntity
    Private _BillingAddress As AddressEntity

    <Key>
    Public Property AMAId() As Guid
        Get
            Return _amaId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Guid)
            _amaId = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property DateOfService() As Nullable(Of Date)
        Get
            Return _DateOfService
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Nullable(Of Date))
            _DateOfService = value
        End Set
    End Property


    'This was used in Castle Activerecord
    '<Nested(ColumnPrefix:="FL")> _
    Public Property FacilityLocation() As AddressEntity
        Get
            Return _FacilityLocation
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As AddressEntity)
            _FacilityLocation = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'This was used in Castle Activerecord
    '<Nested(ColumnPrefix:="BA")> _
    Public Property BillingAddress() As AddressEntity
        Get
            Return _BillingAddress
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As AddressEntity)
            _BillingAddress = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'Other irrelevant properties cut for brevity.

End Class
```

Database table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AMA](
    [AMAId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DateOfService] [datetime] NULL,
    [FLStreet] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FLSuite] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FLCity] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FLZipCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FLCountry] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FLState] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BAStreet] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BASuite] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BACity] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BAZipCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BACountry] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BAState] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AMA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AMAId] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Given the above classes and table structure, can I, and if so, how do I correctly tell Entity Framework how these classes are stored in the database?  I am migrating from Castle ActiveRecord (that sits on top of NHibernate), which used a Nested attribute, with an option column prefix.  Also, I don't know what the correct name (if there is one) for this construct is, I know about TPT, TPC, and TPH, but I haven't found a name for this.

Answer (score 1):

With Entity Framework the terminus technicus for what you call "nested database class" is ["**Complex Type**"](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/03/28/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types.aspx).

In EF terms it is not an "Entity" (which has its own identity and in most cases its own database table), so the name `AddressEntity` is not the best, better would be `AddressType` maybe.

You mark the class itself as "ComplexType", not the single properties in the containing class (like your `FacilityLocation` for example):

```
<ComplexType>
Public Class AddressEntity
'...
```

By default EF will use a column name built up from the `FacilityLocation` property name + underscore + property names of the `AddressEntity`, like

```
FacilityLocation_Street
FacilityLocation_Suite
```

Unfortunately EF doesn't offer such a simple prefix renaming like the `ColumnPrefix` mapping in your example that I am aware of. You must map the properties one by one and you must do it with Fluent API, there is no way to achieve this with data annotations:

(In C#):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AMAStatementEntity>()
    .Property(a => a.FacilityLocation.Street)
    .HasColumnName("FLStreet");

modelBuilder.Entity<AMAStatementEntity>()
    .Property(a => a.FacilityLocation.Suite)
    .HasColumnName("FLSuite");

// etc.
```

Comment: Can making this a "Complex Type" be done with the fluent API?  I ask because I use the AddressEntity in more than the AMAStatementEntity, and in those places it is stored in its own table.

Comment: Think I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931341/entity-framework-reuse-complex-type

Comment: OK, not sure If I'm reading that link correctly but from how I'm looking at it I would have to use 2 different db contexts, 1 for when the AddressEntity is used as a complex type, and 1 for when it is not.

Comment: @David: You cannot mix. A class is *either* a complex type *or* an entity, not sometimes this and sometimes that. You would have to create two different classes for that.