# Entity Framework : map multiple classes to one table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I think this is possible in nhiberate, but my question is about Entity Framework.

In my database model - which I cannot modify - I have redundant columns that I would like to store in different classes.

Example :

```
public class DateParams
{
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }

    // some methods
}

public class Localization
{
    public String EnglishLabel { get; set; }
    public String FrenchLabel { get; set; }

    // some methods
}
```

And then I would use them in some of my models :

```
public class Account // Localization && DateParams 
{
    public int ID { get; set;  }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Localization Localization { get; set; }
    public DateParams DateParams { get; set; }
}

public class Lead // DateParams only
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public DateParams DateParams { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is having something like this

```
public class LocalizationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Localization>
{
   public LocalizationMap()
   { 
        Property(e => e.EnglishLabel).HasColumnName("en");
        Property(e => e.FrenchLabel).HasColumnName("fr");
   }
}

public class AccountMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Account>
{
    public AccountMap()
    {            
        HasKey(x => x.ID);
        Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

        HasSubMapping(new LocalizationMap());
        HasSubMapping(new DateParamsMap());

        ToTable("Account");
    }
}
```

I could use inheritance to solve this, but C# does not allow multiple inheritance.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at Entity Framework Complex Types e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931341/entity-framework-reuse-complex-type

Comment: @ChrifP, could post your comment as an asnwser so that I can accept it? I went by the complextype solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by using complex types. These map to table columns named like `complextypeName_propertyName` but this behaviour can be changed by overwriting `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` in `DbContext` like described in [Entity Framework - Reuse Complex Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931341/entity-framework-reuse-complex-type)

For your example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ComplexType<Localization>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().Property(x => x.Localization.EnglishLabel).HasColumnName("en");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().Property(x => x.Localization.FrenchLabel).HasColumnName("fr");
    // et cetera
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not going to make you happy.

There is an EF feature called *Table Splitting*. As the name suggests, this allows us to map (split) one database table to multiple classes in the conceptual model. In your case, the mappings for `Account` would look like this:

```
class AccountMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Account>
{
    public AccountMap()
    {
        ToTable("Account");
        HasKey(x => x.ID);
        HasRequired(a => a.DateParams).WithRequiredPrincipal();
        HasRequired(a => a.Localization).WithRequiredPrincipal();
    }
}

class DateParamsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<DateParams>
{
    public DateParamsMap()
    {
        ToTable("Account");
    }
}

class LocalizationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Localization>
{
    public LocalizationMap()
    {
        ToTable("Account");
    }
}
```

But this immediately shows the problem: the table name "Account" in the type configurations is hard coded. There's no way to reuse the satellite classes `DateParams` and `Localization` for multiple types. And, before you try, EF won't accept generics like `DateParams<T>`.

Which is sad, because all other options I can think of are ugly, or clunky at best:

- Create subclasses of `DateParams` and `Localization` (and accompanying configurations) for any entity that needs them.
- Just add the properties to all types and work with projections as much as possible (because I assume the whole point of this effort is to reduce the number of properties you're going to query).
- Use one context hosting the main types without these properties and a second context hosting the satellite types (again, to help querying less properties easily). But unfortunately, you can only join the instances from both contexts in memory, i.e. LINQ to objects.
- Create a third satellite class, combining both smaller classes, and use these three classes as base types.